# highlight a word in page with jquery is failing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using this below jQuery function to highlight the word with search logic,

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function (searchWord, className) {
var regex = new RegExp(searchWord, "gi");
return this.each(function () {
    $(this).contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
    }).replaceWith(function () {
        return (this.nodeValue.replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;") || "").replace(regex, function (match) {
            return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + match + "</span>";
        });
    });
});
```

};

[image]

i am searching for the word "your guide to" but due to multiple span tag, the light is not happening. I tried with combining span tags but i facing style issue in page. appreciate your help.

Comment: Is anyone having any idea to resolve this issue?